# Client-side react - no such user after update password

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am a student learning full-stack.

Currently building client-side of app using React with existing server-side code (REST API and database)

Alr created profile-view. The profile view will allow user to update their information.

Problem is that after updating the password, user unable to login. I checked the MongoDB collection, the password is not hashed anymore. Not sure if that's the issue.

How do i solve it?

Below my github pull:
https://github.com/joannawongww/myFlix-client/pull/4

API is from movie_api2 under my repo.

profile-view.jsx

```js
import {
  useState,
  useEffect
} from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import {
  MovieCard
} from "../movie-card/movie-card";
import {
  ModalHeader
} from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  MovieView
} from "../movie-view/movie-view";

export const ProfileView = ({
  user,
  token,
  setUser,
  movies,
  onLogout
}) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState(user.Username);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(user.Email);
  const [birthday, setBirthday] = useState(user.Birthday);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const favoriteMovies = movies.filter((movie) => {
    return user.Favorite.includes(movie.id);
  });

  const handleShowModal = () => setShowModal(true);
  const handleCloseModal = () => setShowModal(false);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      Username: username,
      Password: password,
      Email: email,
      Birthday: birthday,
    };

    fetch(
        `https://myflix-jwww-f51e9c501b1f.herokuapp.com/users/${user.Username}`, {
          method: "PUT",
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json(), alert("Update successfully");
        } else {
          alert("Update failed");
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data));
        setUser(data);
      });
  };

  const handleDeleteUser = () => {
    fetch(
      `https://myflix-jwww-f51e9c501b1f.herokuapp.com/users/${user.Username}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      }
    ).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        onLogout();
      } else {
        alert("Something went wrong.");
      }
    });
  };

  return ( <
    >
    <
    h1 > Profile < /h1> <
    Row >
    <
    Col >
    <
    h3 > Information < /h3> <
    div > Username: {
      user.Username
    } < /div> <
    div > Email: {
      user.Email
    } < /div> <
    /Col>

    <
    Col >
    <
    h3 > Update Profile < /h3> <
    Form onSubmit = {
      handleSubmit
    } >
    <
    Form.Group controlId = "formUsername" >
    <
    Form.Label > Username: < /Form.Label> <
    Form.Control type = "text"
    value = {
      username
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => setUsername(e.target.value)
    }
    required minLength = "5" /
    >
    <
    /Form.Group>

    <
    Form.Group controlId = "formPassword" >
    <
    Form.Label > Password: < /Form.Label> <
    Form.Control type = "password"
    value = {
      password
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => setPassword(e.target.value)
    }
    required minLength = "8" /
    >
    <
    /Form.Group>

    <
    Form.Group controlId = "formEmail" >
    <
    Form.Label > Email: < /Form.Label> <
    Form.Control type = "email"
    value = {
      email
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => setEmail(e.target.value)
    }
    required /
    >
    <
    /Form.Group>

    <
    Form.Group controlId = "formBirthday" >
    <
    Form.Label > Birthday: < /Form.Label> <
    Form.Control type = "date"
    value = {
      birthday
    }
    onChange = {
      (e) => setBirthday(e.target.value)
    }
    required /
    >
    <
    /Form.Group>

    <
    Button variant = "primary"
    type = "submit" >
    Update now <
    /Button> <
    /Form> <
    /Col> <
    /Row>

    <
    Row >
    <
    h3 > Favorite movies < /h3> {
      favoriteMovies.map((movie) => ( <
        Col key = {
          movie.id
        }
        md = {
          4
        } >
        <
        MovieCard movie = {
          movie
        } > < /MovieCard> <
        /Col>
      ))
    } <
    /Row>

    <
    Button variant = "primary"
    onClick = {
      handleShowModal
    } >
    Delete account <
    /Button> <
    Modal show = {
      showModal
    }
    onHide = {
      handleCloseModal
    } >
    <
    Modal.Header closeButton >
    <
    Modal.Title > Delete account < /Modal.Title> <
    /Modal.Header> <
    Modal.Body > Confirm delete account ? < /Modal.Body> <
    Modal.Footer >
    <
    button variant = "primary"
    onClick = {
      handleDeleteUser
    } >
    Yes <
    /button> <
    button variant = "secondary"
    onClick = {
      handleCloseModal
    } >
    No <
    /button> <
    /Modal.Footer> <
    /Modal> <
    />
  );
};
```

movie-view.jsx

```js
import {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";
import {
  useParams
} from "react-router";
import {
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./movie-view.scss";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import {
  ProfileView
} from "../profile-view/profile-view";

export const MovieView = ({
  user,
  token,
  movies,
  setUser
}) => {
  const {
    movieId
  } = useParams();
  const [Favorite, setFavorite] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user ? .Favorite ? .length && movieId) {
      setFavorite(user.Favorite.includes(movieId));
    }
    // const isFavorited = user.Favorite.includes(movieId);
    // setFavorite(isFavorited);
  }, [user.Favorite, movieId]);

  const addFavorite = () => {
    fetch(
        `https://myflix-jwww-f51e9c501b1f.herokuapp.com/users/${user.Username}/movies/${movieId}`, {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setFavorite(true);
        user.Favorite.push(movieId);
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data));
        setUser(user);
      });
  };

  const removeFavorite = () => {
    fetch(
        `https://myflix-jwww-f51e9c501b1f.herokuapp.com/users/${user.Username}/movies/${movieId}`, {
          method: "DELETE",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setFavorite(false);
        user.Favorite = user.Favorite.filter((id) => id !== movieId);
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(data));
        setUser(user);
      });
  };

  const movie = movies.find((movie) => movie.id === movieId);

  return ( <
    div >
    <
    div >
    <
    span >
    <
    img src = {
      movie.ImagePath
    }
    width = "30%" / >
    <
    /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Title: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Title
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Description: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Description
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Genre: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Genre
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Director: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Director
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    <
    div >
    <
    span > Featured: < /span> <
    span > {
      movie.Featured
    } < /span> <
    /div>

    {
      Favorite ? ( <
        Button onClick = {
          removeFavorite
        } > Remove from favourite movies < /Button>
      ) : ( <
        Button onClick = {
          addFavorite
        } > Add to my favorite movies < /Button>
      )
    }

    <
    Link to = {
      `/`
    } >
    <
    Button > Back < /Button> <
    /Link> <
    /div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Possible reason is 'The password is not hashed anymore' and the login api is trying to look for a hashed password. Try fixing the bug of update process in backend api